# hyperlinks are not working in iOS simulator

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios-simulator, hyperlink

I have a jquery mobile web app with hyperlinky `a` tags. Now in all browsers(chrome, safari, opera, firefox, chrome mobile on android) the links are working, but in my xCode iPhone simulator (up to date), it shows the `:active css` state but it don't redirects to the page.

Now I want to ask, is that a jquery mobile error, or xCode error, or something other..

Thanks in advance  :)